# Google Sheets Python Quickstart requires sign in regularly

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

I have set up a script which pulls data from a number of spreadsheets using the Google Sheets API in Python. All works perfectly. However, I noticed that it requires me to manually sign in to my Google account every now and then. More precisely, this happens after a custom clean of my PC's temporary files or a cleaning of my browser's cache data.

However, this affects my script being run autonomously. On the other hand, I cannot and shouldn't let cache and other temporary PC files to pile up just because of this single script. Surely, I can manually approve it every time but that just takes away the point of automation, since I'd need to be always around.

My question is, how can I identify the file where the Python Quickstart application's data is stored and set up an exception to that folder so that Google Chrome, CCleaner and such applications do not remove the data stored within?

I use Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check:

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python

Import pickle should be used to store your credentials and you should just confirm the login manually ones.

The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
time.